# How and where to save my website's files in a cloud server?

Tags: web, server, dns, cloud

Please any help would be really appreciated I am stuck.

I have rented an cloud server through a company online, I have my IP address etc, I am able to connect through SSH and install libraries etc.

Now my question is how to upload my html files on the server and where to save them. So when I go into my website address (I have purchased a domain and also connected it through DNS to my cloud server), to be able to bring the website up.

**Edit: Is using Plesk(already comes with the server) my answer?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/ might be better suited for this question

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check it out.